# db returns NoneType, in flask documentation

Tags: python, flask

```
def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        
        return g.db
```

Hello, trying to learn flask. Currently going through it's documentation, just completed the tutorial for a simple app. For some reason I'm getting this error.

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

```
@bp.route('/')
def index():
    db = get_db()
    
    posts = db.execute(
        'SELECT p.id, title, body, created, author_id, username'
        ' FROM post p JOIN user u ON p.author_id = u.id'
        ' ORDER BY created DESC'
    ).fetchall()
    # returns template, with the posts as parameter
    return render_template('blog/index.html', posts=posts)
```

This is where I'm getting an error. I also use the get_db() on other code and it works, but for some reason for index it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe 'db' not in g?

Comment: @funnydman yep, python and indentation. Weibeu got it right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `get_db` function, you haven't handled the case where `db` is present in `g`.
What you can do is that, you can put your return statement outside the first `'db' not in g` if check (which ensures that `g.db` is not None in all of the cases). This way, if `db` isn't present in `g` it will set it there and in all cases it will return `g.db`.